# internet connection in debian 6's recovery mode

Tags: debian, internet

I've broken my window manager on my Debian 6 machine, and so I am stuck to recovery mode for now. That is, I got a plain root shell. Now here's my problem: how can I get a internet connection, so I can pull new sources and compile my window manager?

```
ifconfig eth0 up
/etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

does not work. eth0 is up, but I cannot access the internet. What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `dhclient eth0` if it's a direct connection to your ISP or there's a DHCP server in your network.

Can you ping hosts in your network, if any? Please post the output of `ifconfig eth0` and `route -n`.

Comment: ip addr sh and ip ro sh - also come to play as ifconfig and route should be considered deprecated (but yes, they still work).

Comment: @cstamas: true, but old habits die hard! `netstat -nr` can also replace `route`.

Comment: nice, did not know the latter.